# the subgroup of index 14 in the simple group of order 1092

Tags: finite-groups, sylow-theory

Let $G$ be a simple group of order 1092, the question is that why it has a single conjugacy class of subgroups of index 14?

Personally, I have compute the number of Sylow 13-subgroups, it is 14. By using the subgroup $N_G(P)$, where $P\in$ sylow 13-subgroup. But how to prove there is only one conjugacy class?

Comment: I suppose you can use the fact that in a group of order $1092/14 = 78$ a $13$-Sylow subgroup is normal.

Comment: Yeah, I have tried using Sylow theorem again that there is only one sylow 13-subgroup in $N_G(P)$, however, there is one question that if two groups of order 78 contain the same sylow 13-subgroup, is there some contradiction?

Comment: Yes, the Sylow subgroup is normal in both, and thus in their span.