# Simple group of order $1092 =2^2\cdot 3\cdot 7\cdot 13$ has a single conjugacy class of subgroups of index $14$, but no subgroup of index $13$

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups, sylow-theory, simple-groups

> Let $G$ be a simple group of order $1092 =2^2\cdot 3\cdot7\cdot13.$ Prove that $G$ has a single conjugacy class of subgroups of index $14,$ but no subgroup of index $13.$

Extending from this post: [the subgroup of index 14 in the simple group of order 1092](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2413213/the-subgroup-of-index-14-in-the-simple-group-of-order-1092), I want to prove that there is no subgroups of index $13$. I have managed to show that $G$ has a single conjugacy class of subgroups of index $14$ using the hints provided in the previous post. However, I can't seem to show that there is no subgroup of index $13.$

So far I tried to use the technique mentioned on page 204-205 of Dummit and Foote.

> "Let $G$ be a simple group with a proper subgroup of index $k$. If $P\in{\rm Syl}_p(G)$ and if $P$ is also a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $A_k$, then $|N_G(P)|$ must divide $|N_{A_k}(P)|$"

Let $P$ be a $13$-Sylow subgroup of $G$. Then, from my calculations, $|N_G(P)|=|N_{A_k}(P)|=2\cdot 3\cdot 13$ which is sadly not sufficient to get the desired contradiction.
Is there any other ways to improve on my technique? If not, can somebody provide some hints on how to proceed.

Comment: Are you looking for a solution at the Dummit and Foote level or is this for a course in finite groups?  (Your question is the q=13 term in an infinite sequence, but q=11 is exceptional: a simple group of order $2^2\cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 11$ does have a subgroup of index 11. Those seem very similar, but have different answers, so I worry some detail is going to be needed in any answer.)

Comment: @JackSchmidt I am an undergraduate student at the moment. So it would be sufficient to just prove that simple groups of order $2^2\cdot 3\cdot 5 \cdot 13$ doesn't have a subgroup of index 13. I don't think at my current level I will be able to understand a general solution to simple groups of order $2^2\cdot 3\cdot 5 \cdot q$. You can try though. I am willing to learn.

Comment: But I thought you were asking about a group of order $2^2 \cdot 3 \cdot 7 \cdot 13$.

Comment: @DerekHolt Ya I am asking about a group of order $2^2\cdot 3 \cdot 7 \cdot 13$. But Jack Schmidt seems to give me the impression that this can be generalised to $2^2\cdot 3 \cdot 7 \cdot q$

Comment: The pattern is that a simple group of order $q(q-1)(q+1)/2$ exists for all odd prime powers $q\geq 5$, but it only very rarely has a subgroup of index $q$ (largest exception is $q=11$)

Comment: @DerekHolt Just realised that Jack Schmidt was talking about groups of order $2^2\cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 11$ and not $2^2\cdot 3 \cdot 7 \cdot 11$ that was in my original poster. Thanks for catching that. Read your solution. It was very clear. Thanks

Comment: @JackSchmidt Cool. Didn't know this. Probably beyond my level. Hahahaha

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A subgroup $H$ of index $13$ would have order $84$, and so by Sylow's Theorem would have a normal Sylow $7$-subgroup $P$.

So $H \le N_G(P)$. If $H = N_G(P)$, then $G$ has $13$ Sylow $7$-subgroups, contradicting Sylow's Theorem. So by Lagrange we must have $N_G(P) = G$, contradicting simplicity.

Comment: (+1) Is it easy to prove a simple group of order $2^2\cdot 3^2 \cdot 5\cdot 19$ has no subgroup of index 19? "Does something like this work for all q or was q=13 nicer than usual?"

Comment: I think so. Since $19 \not\equiv 1 \bmod 5$, if $H$ is such a subgroup  and $P \in {\rm Syl}_5(H)$, then we cannot have $N_H(P) = N_G(P)$, so $|N_G(P)|$ must be divisible by $19$, but then $|N_G(Q)|$ is divisible by $5$ for $Q \in {\rm Syl}_{19}(G)$, which forces $Q \lhd G$. But  I don't see this leading to a more general proof that ${\rm PSL}(2,q)$ has no subgroup of index $q$ for $q>11$.

Comment: Thanks! Something like this might work for "half" of the odd primes q. Look at the largest prime factor of q-1 versus q+1. If q+1 has the larger factor, then I think this works. That leaves lots of other numbers q, but I think this fits well with Dummit and Foote's section on "playing primes off one another".